# $\langle Tx,x \rangle =0$ then $T=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a complex Hilbert space $H$, we have that $\langle Tx,x \rangle =0$ then $T=0$ holds.

I looked to some old threads and all of them talked about this by referring to the polarization identity, but I could not find a full proof.

I know that the polarization identitfy tells us that

$$\langle Tx,x \rangle = \frac{1}{4} (||Tx+x||^2-||Tx-x||^2+ i ||Tx+ix||^2- i||Tx-ix||^2)$$ but how do I see from this that $T=0$?

Comment: I assume you mean "we have that for any $x \in H$, $\langle Tx, x\rangle = 0$".

Comment: @Arthur yes, I mean that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $f(x,y)=\langle Tx,y\rangle$. f is bilinear on $H$ and by  generalized polarization identity
one has

$$
\langle Tx,y\rangle =\frac{1}{4}\{   \langle T(x+y),x+y \rangle - \langle T(x-y),x-y \rangle\}+
\frac{1}{4}i\{   \langle T(x+iy),x+iy \rangle - \langle T(x-iy),x-iy \rangle\}.
$$
If $\langle Tx,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in H$, then  $\langle Tx,y\rangle=0$ for all $x,y\in H$. If we put $y=Tx$, Then $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=0$, that is, $Tx=0$ for all $x$. This means $T=0$.